# Re-rendering of children on click doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently learning React and am trying to code a programmable grid where the boxes change color when clicked.

Unfortunately my 'Refresh Grid'-button is not working as intended. Even when clicked the boxes which got clicked before remain activated (i.e. their color is orange).
As I reset the state of my grid when calling the `setGrid()` I am not sure where I am mistaken.

Help is much appreciated. As I am totally new to React itself some recommendations about best practices etc. would be of great help as well!

Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

class Box extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      color: 'white',
      activated: false
    }
  }

  initiate() {
    this.setState({color: 'white', activated:false})
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.initiate()
  }

  click() {
    if(!this.state.activated) {
      this.setState({color: 'orange', activated: true})
    }
    else {
      this.setState({color: 'white', activated: false})
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <div className="box" style={{ backgroundColor: this.state.color }} onClick={() => this.click()}/>
  }
} 

class Grid extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {grid: []}
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setGrid()
  }

  setGrid() {
    let grid = [];
    for (let row = 0; row < 20; row++) {
      for (let col = 0; col < 20; col++) {
        grid.push(<Box />)
      }
    }
    this.setState({grid: grid})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="grid">{this.state.grid}</div>
        <button onClick={() => this.setGrid()}>Refresh Grid</button>
      </>
      )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Grid />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't assigning a React key to the elements/Components rendered in the array, so their relative index is used, and since this ***doesn't*** change from render to render, React bails on rerendering.

1. You can assign unique keys to each `Box` component when they are instantiated into the `grid` state. Here's an example using a GUID generator from `uuid`.

   ```
   import { v4 as uuidV4 } from 'uuid';

   ...

   setGrid() {
     let grid = [];
     for (let row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
       for (let col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
         grid.push(<Box key={uuidV4()} />); // <-- add key
       }
     }
     this.setState({ grid: grid });
   }
   ```

[image: Edit re-rendering-of-children-on-click-doesnt-work]

2. You can use a single key on the `div` rendering the `grid`. Reset this when setting/resetting the grid.

   ```
   import { v4 as uuidV4 } from 'uuid';

   ...

   class Grid extends React.Component {
     constructor() {
       super();
       this.state = {
         grid: [],
         key: uuidV4()
       };
     }

     componentDidMount() {
       this.setGrid();
     }

     setGrid() {
       const grid = [];
       for (let row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
         for (let col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
           grid.push(<Box />);
         }
       }
       this.setState({
         grid,
         key: uuidV4() // <-- set/reset key
       });
     }

     render() {
       return (
         <>
           <div
             key={this.state.key} // <-- add key
             className="grid"
           >
             {this.state.grid}
           </div>
           <button onClick={() => this.setGrid()}>Refresh Grid</button>
         </>
       );
     }
   }
   ```

   [image: Edit re-rendering-of-children-on-click-doesnt-work (forked)]

Answer (score 0):

Clear the existing grid and set the new grid

```
  setGrid() {
    this.setState({ grid: [] }, () => {
      let grid = [];
      for (let row = 0; row < 20; row++) {
        for (let col = 0; col < 20; col++) {
          grid.push(<Box />);
        }
      }
      this.setState({ grid: grid });
    });
  }
```